# Is there a way to convert values in dictionary to integers depending on the set( ) value? (similar to label encoder)

Tags: python

Is there a way to change the values of my dictionary to integers?

Like the `scikit learn` `LabelEncoder`?

for example

`mydict = {'a': 'apple', 'b': 'apple', 'c': 'grape'}`
to

`mydict = {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 1}`

I was able to do the job by doing

`{j: i for i, j in enumerate(set(mydict.values()))}`
so I have a new dictionary with `{'apple': 0, 'grape': 1}`

then convert it by using

`mydict.items()`.
I was wondering if there is any other efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done naturally with [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```py
>>> mydict = {'a': 'apple', 'b': 'apple', 'c': 'grape'}
>>> counter = {}
>>> {k: counter.setdefault(v, len(counter)) for k, v in mydict.items()}
{'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 1}
```

You could also do it with a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```py
>>> mydict = {'a': 'apple', 'b': 'apple', 'c': 'grape'}
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> counter = defaultdict(lambda: len(counter))
>>> {k: counter[v] for k, v in mydict.items()}
{'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 1}
```

However, be aware that the lambda here (necessarily) uses late binding on the name `counter`, so if you ever reassign `counter` then any alias to the defaultdict will stop working. You can avoid this by assigning the `default_factory` attribute once the dictionary is already created; here's a factory function which does that:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
def make_counter():
    counter = defaultdict()
    counter.default_factory = counter.__len__
    return counter
```

Answer (score 0):

This code does what you want:

```
{a : int(b == 'grape') for a, b in mydict.items()}
```

`b == name` Gives `True` or `False`. Then by `int()` It changes to `1` or `0`

I made simple function by using above.(`name` can be even a list):

```
def to_int(name, dic):
    return {a : int(b == name if type(name) != type(list()) else b in name) for a, b in dic.items()}
```

Full code:

```
mydict = {'a': 'apple', 'b': 'apple', 'c': 'grape'}

def to_int(name, dic):
    return {a : int(b == name if type(name) != type(list()) else b in name) for a, b in dic.items()}

print(to_int('grape', mydict))
print(to_int(['grape', 'apple'], mydict))
```

Output:

```
{'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 1}
{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}
```

Comment: thanks! but the problem is, what if there's more than two values? like 'apple', 'grape', 'pear'....

Comment: Ok, I changed the code. Please check now.

Comment: Though the result would lead all values to 1 for the second example